# System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: REQUIRED_FIELD_MISSING in test class

Tags: apex, unit-test

Class:

```
public class CreatePurchaseorder{

    public Purchase_order_setting__c pos {get;set;}

    public boolean isInput{get;set;}

    public id poid{get;set;}

    public boolean isUpdt{get;set;}

    public boolean isSave{get;set;}

    public boolean isdeleter{get;set;}

    public boolean iscancel{get;set;}
    
    public CreatePurchaseorder(){

        pos = new Purchase_order_setting__c ();
        isInput = true;
        isSave = true;
        iscancel=true;
        isUpdt = false;
        Id poid= ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('poid');

      String nm = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('str');

        pos .Name= NM;
        
        
    }
    
    public void saveCon(){
       
        insert pos ;
        isInput = false;
        isSave = false;
        //isUpdt = false;
    }
     public void Cancel(){
      insert pos ;
        isInput = false;
        isSave = false;
         iscancel=false;
        }
      
    
    public void editCon(){
        isInput = true;
        isSave = false;
        isUpdt = true;
    }
    
    public void updateCon(){
        isSave = false;
        update pos ;
        isUpdt = false;
        isInput = false;
    }
    
}
```

Test class :

```
@isTest
    public class CreatePurchaseorderTest{

        static testmethod void CreatePurchaseorderTestMethod(){   
 
        Purchase_order_setting__c objPurchaseOrder = new Purchase_order_setting__c();
      
        objPurchaseOrder.name= 'musqot';

        objPurchaseOrder.PO_Startnumber__c= 1;

        System.assertEquals('musqot', objPurchaseOrder.name);

        insert objPurchaseOrder;

        ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().put('id', objPurchaseOrder.id);

        ApexPages.StandardController sc = new ApexPages.standardController(objPurchaseOrder);

        test.startTest();

        CreatePurchaseorder objcrePurchase = new CreatePurchaseorder();

        objcrePurchase.saveCon();

        objcrePurchase.Cancel();

        objcrePurchase.editCon();

        objcrePurchase.updateCon();
             }
        }
```

I'm getting this error:

> Error Message System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: REQUIRED_FIELD_MISSING, Required fields are missing: [PO_Startnumber__c]: [PO_Startnumber__c]
>
> Stack Trace   Class.CreatePurchaseorder.saveCon: line 25, column 1
>
> Class.CreatePurchaseorderTest.CreatePurchaseorderTestMethod: line 15, column 1

Comment: I reckon the PO_Startnumber__c field is missing.

Comment: i already assign that field in my test class..

Comment: yeah but in the wrong place, i think you're not understanding whats happening in your code, the error is pretty clear it tells you that a required field is missing in saveCon

Answer (score 2):

I think you mistakenly think that by setting the `PO_Startnumber__c` as follows:

```
objPurchaseOrder.PO_Startnumber__c= 1;
```

Prior to creating a `CreatePurchaseorder` instance:

```
    CreatePurchaseorder objcrePurchase = new CreatePurchaseorder();

    objcrePurchase.saveCon();
```

That you are somehow setting the `PO_Startnumber__c` within `CreatePurchaserorder`.

I think you need to set the `PO_Startnumber__c` on the `objcrePurchase` instance:

```
    CreatePurchaseorder objcrePurchase = new CreatePurchaseorder();
    objcrePurchase.pos.PO_Startnumber__c = 1;
    objcrePurchase.saveCon();
```